# Rails LIKE query not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This works correctly, and returns correct results:

```
query = params[:query].downcase
users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['username LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"])
```

However, I think this is unsafe as it is open to SQL injection attacks?

So I'm trying to do to it like this:

```
users = User.all(:conditions => ["username LIKE ?", query])
```

or even

```
users = User.where("username LIKE ?", query)
```

but neither of those 2 return any results.

What's the correct way to do this?

**Edit:**
This works:

```
users = User.where("username LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
```

But according to Rails docs:

[image]

Comment: Your last edited example is not doing what the example in the red image block is doing. Notice how they aren't passing in an array to sanitize the query.

Comment: @Nighthawk441 not sure what you mean..I can't see the difference between what I'm doing and what they're doing.

Comment: @moby the difference is you're using the `?` in all 3 of your examples, whereas the Rails warning doesn't use the `?`.

Comment: Notice how in their example they aren't passing two objects. It's Client.where("first_name LIKE '%#{params[:first_name]}%') which is unsafe because rails isn't constructing the query string. So your examples look safe to me.

Comment: Are you using this for searching? I'm not 100% sure but awhile ago in our scrum my boss told me you shouldn't use SQL LIKE for searching, use some specialized engine like Solr. (Not 100% sure on this one though so anyone can feel free to correct me.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the percentage symbol in your alternative attempts at the query:

```
query = "%thing_to_find%"
users = User.all(:conditions => ["username LIKE ?", query])
```

-or-

```
query = "%thing_to_find%"
users = User.where("username LIKE ?", query)
```

But with that said, your first example is safe from SQL injection. In fact all three of your examples are AOK!

Comment: What is the percentage for? Also, was I correct that my initial attempt was open to SQL injection attacks, or was it safe?

Comment: The percent sign tells SQL to do a wildcard match

Comment: Please note that, since you're using the input string for a LIKE, you should escape that string in order to guarantee exact matching; that is, if `thing_to_find` is `"%"`, your query will become `username LIKE '%%%'`, which f.e. in PostgreSQL matches everything